# Javascript Hide Show getElementById vs getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a very simple working function to show a div by clicking a link:

```
function show() {
document.getElementById('box').style.display="block";
}

<a href="javascript:show();">Show</a>
<div id="box" style="display:none;">
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

But now, when i simply change the div from an id to a class and replace getElementById to getElementByClassName, it does not work anymore:

```
function show() {
document.getElementByClassName('box').style.display="block";
}

<a href="javascript:show();">Show</a>
<div class="box" style="display:none;">
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: getElementByClassName or getElementsByClassName

Comment: It is frustrated. I posted the same reason as all others posted. Mine is downvoted.Others are not. Deleting my answer

Comment: @user3168736: if I'm not mistaking, you started off with "There is no `getElementByClass` method. U have to use `getElementsByClass`", without iteration.

Comment: @FrankConijn yea my answer is still present

Comment: @user3168736 then you copy pasted a wrong answer and added it to your answer. Then you saw it was wrong and you copy pasted someone elses answer again, this time the right one.

Comment: @fonZ Mind your words. What do u mean by copy paste?? Do u think that am senseless.. See my profile, Answered only CSS questions. It shows you that i have sense in designing.

Comment: @fonZ show me the source u meant that i copied if u can. Don't use unnecessary words

Comment: @fonz if  u have authority, see all my edits for this question.Then u know who posted the right answer first and remains same ..

Comment: @user3168736 You copy pasted my (deleted) answer, it was pretty obvious. Then you did it again with my actual answer, that i improved later. It's ok i understand you want to climb the ladder but like this its not really honest, especially when you lie about it. Shame on you! End of discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the script in principle should look like:

```
function show() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

.
**EDIT**:
Be it that IE8 doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`. If you want to code for that browser as well, which you should imo, this is the script you should use:

```
function show() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');   // mind the dot
    for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

.
`getElementById` is supported by IE8, just as `getElementsByTagName`, for your information.

Comment: @rainerbrunotte: you're welcome. But have a look at the edited version, for functionality in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
function show() {
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('box').length;i++){
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i].style.display="block";
}
}
```

**PS :** NOTE **s** in getElement **s** ByClassName

Comment: I tried this but found that I had the replace int with var to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.display="block";
                   ^                   ^
```

for 1st element of that class

check [document.getElementsByClassName](http://document.getElementsByClassNamehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace `getElementByClassName` with `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: No, he needs to iterate through the returned array as well. Otherwise it still won't work.

Comment: your right, maybe you should post how to iterate the returned array for him to be guided. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I didnt quite notice, actually I was the one who upvoted you.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It is **[getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)**

```
var classInstances = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var n;
for (n = 0; n < classInstances.length; n++) {
   classInstances[n].style.display="block";
}
```

So you forgot the **s** And if you think about it, it's pure logic.

An **id** is a **unique** identification number. A **class** on the contrary is **not unique**, there can be more of them. So it's logic that you have to find them all and iterate over them to get the right one.